# How can I create a pdf file from html5 + css3?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

I need convert an html + css to pdf. The target is generate an invoice.

Comment: None of the answer and the other post indicated as possible duplicate explains about converting Html5, css3 to pdf.

Comment: Exactly. Why the hell is it a duplicate?

Answer (score -1):

use this

http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

```
$html = file_get_contents("valid.html");
require_once("html2pdf.class.php");
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF("P", "A4", "en", array(10, 10, 10, 10));
$html2pdf->setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$html2pdf->Output("pdf/PDF.pdf", "F"); //output to file
$html2pdf->Output(); //output to browser
```

Comment: does it works with html5 and css3? i tried others and it didnt work

Comment: Does it work with specifically CSS3? Others only supported up to CSS2.1